# Easiest way to set up a workstation with TV and multiple monitors

Tags: multiple-monitors, tv

In my bedroom, I have a PC, two monitors, and an HD television. I'd like to set these all up to work together in two modes:

1. Working on the PC - in this mode the two monitors should be enabled and the TV wouldn't be used.
2. Watching videos, or playing games on the big screen - in this mode a full screen application would be used (XBMC, VLC or a game) on the TV, and the two monitors wouldn't be used.

I'll never need to use both the TV and monitors at the same time.

My PC currently has two outputs (from its motherboard) - a DVI and VGA. It is able to use both simultaneously, so connecting two monitors is trivial. Using a TV as well, however, is more complicated. How would you suggest I connect the TV?

Should I buy an extra graphics card for an extra output port? Is there a DVI switch I should use instead? Or maybe an entirely different idea I hadn't thought of?